# How to understand the different types of values mentioned in CSS specification?

Tags: css

In the CSS specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#declared-value), section 4 talks about different types of values. Have I understood the concept correctly?

Say I have these two CSS rules in the same file

```
p {
color:red;
}

p{
color:blue;
}
```

Am I correct that

1. -the `color` property of `p` is `declared value`?
2. The `cascaded` value of color is `blue`?
3. The `specified` value is `blue`. In case I had not declared this value, the -`specified` value would have been some default value?
4. The computed value is `blue`. If I had used some relative values eg. em, % (not valid for the color example though) then the computed
   value would have been some absolute number?
5. Used value is the value which could be realistically used. eg if computed value is 4.2px then used value would be 4px (as browser
   can't do 0.2 px)

Comment: Would be useful for you to set up a more robust example, so that you could properly discuss / identify when a cascade value is being used, the nuance in the used value, etc.  Your example code isn't helping draw out the differences very clearly.

Comment: Yeah, cascading gets more interesting with the different rules of dominance in specificity. In your case, it's just that the last value of equal specificity wins.

Comment: Thanks. I know the example I used isn't great but I am trying to understand the principle of how css works. It seems that if no css rule is declared for an element then some browser specific default value is used (or maybe some value inherited from parent). If a rule is specified for an element then cascading decided which rule wins (as different rules could apply to an element because of specificity). Also, relative values (eg `auto`, `inherit`, `initial` are converted to absolute values (eg 3em to `14px`). Values might also get rounded off (eg 14.2 px to 14px).